# Is there a way to export and Excel sheet without copying to a workbook?

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I have a workbook that can export the working sheet to a .csv but it copies it into a new workbook for a second before saving im wondering if there is a way just to copy data from the sheet as is without opening a new workbook ? the code i have is:

```
        Sub CopyToCSV()

        Dim FlSv As Variant
        Dim MyFile As String
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim MyFileName As String
        Dim DateString As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        DateString = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy_hh-mm-ss-AM/PM") '<~~ uses current time from computer clock down to the second
        MyFileName = "Results - " & DateString

        Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
        sh.Copy
        FlSv = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(MyFileName, fileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Where should we save this?")

     If FlSv = False Then GoTo UserCancel Else GoTo UserOK

UserCancel:             '<~~ this code is run if the user cancels out the file save dialog
        ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
        MsgBox "Export Canceled"
        Exit Sub

UserOK:                 '<~~ this code is run if user proceeds with saving the file (clicks the OK button)
        MyFile = FlSv
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs (MyFile), FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            .Close False
        End With

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: Yes there is a way but it is a complex process as compared to what you have. IWhat you have is much easy

Comment: thanks for the reply is this code posted anywhere? id like to test it out !

Comment: the reason i need it is because i use VaySoft Excel to EXE Converter so nobody at my work can steal my code and claim its their own to my boss (This has happened many times). The problem is it protects the sheet and does not allow another workbook to open so it breaks the export function

Comment: Well I am not sure where is it online because I have it in my code database :)

Comment: ok well if you have chance to find it when you have some time id really appreciate it ive finished another project for work and ive beel learning vb in excel im no master but i have managed to make everything work apart from this so i would really appreciate any help

Comment: I couldn't find it so I am writing it from scratch.. gimme 15 mins

Comment: @AndrewWalker - can I ask how to contact you privately?

Comment: @RomcelGeluz sorry for my long reply. sure email me at jimbob12342@hotmail.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (**tested on a simple dataset**)

```
Private Sub ExportToCsv()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim delim As String, LastCol As String, csvFile As String, CsvLine As String
    Dim aCell As Range, DataRange As Range
    Dim ff As Long, lRow As Long, lCol As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    '~~> We use "," as delimiter
    delim = ","

    '~~> Change this to specify your file name and path
    csvFile = "C:\Users\Siddharth\Desktop\Sample.Csv"

    '~~> Change this to the sheet which you want to export as csv
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9")

    With ws
        '~~> Find last row and last column
        lRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Row

        lCol = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                After:=.Range("A1"), _
                Lookat:=xlPart, _
                LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                MatchCase:=False).Column

        '~~> Column number to column letter
        LastCol = Split(Cells(, lCol).Address, "$")(1)

        '~~> This is the range which will be exported
        Set DataRange = .Range("A1:" & LastCol & lCol)

        '
        '~~> Loop through cells in the range and write to text file
        '

        ff = FreeFile

        Open csvFile For Output As #ff

        For i = 1 To lRow
            For j = 1 To lCol
                CsvLine = CsvLine & (delim & Replace(.Cells(i, j).Value, """", """"""""))
            Next j

            Print #ff, Mid(CsvLine, 2)

            CsvLine = ""
        Next

        '~~> Close text file
        Close #ff
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: That just worked brilliantly! THANK YOU so much! im goin to try and edit it to saveas with a save as box now but that should be easy thanks again!

Comment: @SiddharthRout another nice +1 Just out of curioisity, why are you so locked on using `Set DataRange = .Range("A1:" & LastCol & lCol)` ? why not `Set DataRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))` ? any difference , you can save a "precious" 1 code line

Comment: @ShaiRado: Old Habit I guess. Somehow I do not like `.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(lRow, lCol))` LOL

Comment: Worth concatenating your string `CsvLine = CsvLine & (delim & Replace(.Cells(i, j).Value, """", """"""""))`

Comment: Long time @brettdj :) Sure will do it but would like to know what difference would the brackets make?

Comment: Hi Sid :) Much better to concatenate your long string once in an operation.

Comment: Such a lucky guy make sir Sid write a code from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CopyToCSV()

        Dim FlSv As Variant
        Dim MyFile As String
        Dim sh As Worksheet
        Dim MyFileName As String
        Dim strTxt As String

        Dim vDB, vR() As String, vTxt()
        Dim i As Long, n As Long, j As Integer
        Dim objStream
        Dim strFile As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        DateString = Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy_hh-mm-ss-AM/PM") '<~~ uses current time from computer clock down to the second
        MyFileName = "Results - " & DateString

        FlSv = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(MyFileName, fileFilter:="CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv), *.csv", Title:="Where should we save this?")

     If FlSv = False Then GoTo UserCancel Else GoTo UserOK

UserCancel:             '<~~ this code is run if the user cancels out the file save dialog
        ActiveWorkbook.Close (False)
        MsgBox "Export Canceled"
        Exit Sub

UserOK:                 '<~~ this code is run if user proceeds with saving the file (clicks the OK button)

    Set objStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    MyFile = FlSv
    vDB = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    For i = 1 To UBound(vDB, 1)
        n = n + 1
        ReDim vR(1 To UBound(vDB, 2))
        For j = 1 To UBound(vDB, 2)
            vR(j) = vDB(i, j)
        Next j
        ReDim Preserve vTxt(1 To n)
        vTxt(n) = Join(vR, ",")
    Next i
    strtxt = Join(vTxt, vbCrLf)
    With objStream
        .Charset = "utf-8"
        .Open
        .WriteText strtxt
        .SaveToFile FlSv, 2
        .Close
    End With
    Set objStream = Nothing

        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: This works brilliant too Thanks SO SO much. when compiling to an exe it give an error 400 when saving but it saves completely fine any ideas why ?

Comment: Dim strFile As String   is missed.

Comment: Thanks i tried that but just works exactly the same. works perfectly but throws up error 400 at the end

Comment: Dim strTxt As String is missed not  "Dim strFile As String"

Comment: error numver 400 msd describe "You can't use the Show method to display a visible form as modal. This error has the following cause and solution: "